Company-mode in style tag
I setup company-mode and company-lsp for html and css and js file but cannot activate it for html file while working with style tag ().
<style>
 html {
  font-size:
  margin:
  ..
}
</style

I dont have auto-suggestion for font-size or margin; I need to type all the world; also for value of the properties.  Like if I type pa I've got "param" and not padding as autocompletion.
Thk.

What IDE do you use?

Emacs 27.1 and Pop OS 22.04

Ok I find, just company-css was not push into backend.

I find.. company-css was not pushed in company-backends
